# How can we track stored procedure changes in SQL Server like version control in TFS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have some issues in security like someone who has access to SQL Server is changing the procedure without the team's knowledge. So we would like to know who did any changes from which PC in what time and those logs.

Is there is any Microsoft tools or any third party softwares for that purpose?

I tried Redgate SQL Compare which you can use for some little comparisons. But it won't have all the version controls or history logs from multiple variants.

Comment: It is quite easy to write a DDL trigger to log changes. The answer supplied here: [Track Stored Procedure Changes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b1628c9a-f2de-46b3-9323-195172a21da3/track-stored-procedure-changes?forum=sqlexpress) could easily be adapted to log username and date.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: @Tanner Sorry bro.. situation little worse.. thats why I requested for help

Comment: Why does someone outside the team have rights to install procedures?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend keeping database objects under version control rather than trying to manage changes solely in a physical database. This will allow you to commit database changes to source control along with code changes and keep a change history.

Microsoft provides Visual Studio with source control integration along with SQL Server Data Tools to facilitate this. There are also third party products, Red-Gate SQL Source Control and Apex Source Control, which integrate with SSMS and/or Visual Studio.  These products provide tooling to reconcile database changes but it us ultimately up to your developers/DBAs to use these tools properly and adhere to a defined process for development and promotion of changes to other environments.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there is any Microsoft tools...

Yes, use `TFS` source control for this purpose as well. Create a `DB Project` from Visual Studio template and include all your procedure in that project. Now you can track the changes as you would do for application code (probably using `C#`)

Comment: Don't forget to mention the security aspects too. Using VS, TFS and whatever is nice, but you won't detect a change in production when it is done by hand. Even if it will be overwritten with the next release, an untracked change was in effect for some time.

Answer (score 1):

> . So we would like to know who did any changes from which PC in what time and those logs.

Some of this information is available from SQL server's built in reports in SMSS. In SMSS, right-click on the affected database and select Reports-->Standard Reports-->Schema Changes History. This will give you the DDL Operation, Time, Login Name and User Name of the person running the DDL operation. The report is unable to provide the PC that the DDL was run from.

This information is taken from the SQL Server's default trace. You can query the default trace if it is enabled use the techniques shown at https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/a-few-cool-things-you-can-identify-using-the-default-trace.html

Comment: What data source does ***that*** report pull from, though? If it was a table that could be queried in SQL, then this would be a lot more flexible than the clunky report workaround (which takes a while to run, and is only searchable by exporting it to Excel... )

Comment: @eriegz I have added details of the source to my answer.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried the query on that page (specifically, the one under "Listing 5"), but it seems to not be returning the same data that's available in the "Schema Changes History" report. I've also tried other similar queries like the solution on [this page](https://blog.sqlterritory.com/2018/11/20/5-ways-to-track-database-schema-changes-part-1-default-trace/) (in the "Using T-SQL" section) which actually gave more readable output, but again didn't return the same data as the "Schema Changes History" report... ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an enforced source\version control for SQL Server - have a look at [dbmaestro](http://dbmaestro.com)

This is the only tool that is locking the DB for changes at the DB level so even with command line you will need to do proper check out before doing changes and once you check in you have full history with all revisions.